# Edit the search results page?

Tags: search

I would like to edit the search results page to include a side bar with content such as some links, can someone please tell me the file to edit? Do I need to create a new template?

Help me out please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a CMS static block widget for this.

1. In the admin panel, head to `CMS > Static Blocks` and create your content
2. Then in `CMS > Widgets`, select **CMS Static Block Widget**
3. Select your theme
4. Choose your static block in **Widget Options**
5. In **Layout Updates**, choose "*Specified Page*", and then select the search page(s) and location where you want to display this block

Comment: On rare occasion, Magento makes it pretty darn easy to do what you want to do w/ no coding required ;-)

Comment: Thanks. One more question, if I want to edit out the product page(that means the page which shows info about the product) what is the procedure I should follow?

Comment: What do you mean by "edit out"?

Answer (score 1):

In `local.xml` file you can change the layout and can add/remove blocks in the left or right column. For example:

```
<catalogsearch_result_index>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/3columns.phtml</template>
            <!-- or 2columns-left or 2columns-right -->
        </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="left">
        <!-- Remove some unnecessary blocks -->
        <remove name="block.name.here" />

        <block type="yourmodule/yourblock" name="somename" after="currency" template="yourmodule/yourblock/left.phtml"/>
    </reference> 
</catalogsearch_result_index>
```

For showing the block immediately without calling it from the template file just add `output="toHtml"` in `<block>` element.

You can also add static (CMS) block if you don't have some logic to implement:

```
<block type="cms/block" name="search_result_links">
    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>search_result_links</block_id></action>
</block>
```